# Are component refs accessible in mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I have a simple React component that has two inputs and dispatches an action to add an item to a catalog using the input values.

```
# components/addProduct.jsx

import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const AddProduct = ({
  onClick
}) => {
  let title, price

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit= { (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
      }}
    >
      Title: <input ref={ node => {title = node;}} type="text"/><br />
      Price: <input ref={ node => {price = node;}} type="text"/><br />
      <button onClick={onClick}>Create New Product</button>
    </form>
  )
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      console.log("Firing on click for button")
      console.log(this)               # => mapToPropsProxy
      console.log(AddProduct.refs)    # => undefined

      dispatch({                      # This will be a call to addProduct(title, price) later
        type: "ADD_PRODUCT",
        title: this.refs.title.value, # ???
        price: this.refs.price.value
      })
    }
  }
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddProduct)
```

I can't access the refs I declared in my AddProduct component. This makes intuitive sense; AddProduct doesn't really even exist until `connect` resolves the first time with `mapDispatchToProps` and it gets exported.

So how can I access the input values? Am I architecting this incorrectly?

Comment: I know I COULD move the dispatch into the component, but if I understand correctly I should be separating RENDERING from LOGIC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are architecting this incorrectly, your function will get dispatch injected into it, so the vars you need to pass are not part of the context were it this declared, you should do something like:

```
<button onClick={() => {this.props.onClick(this.refs.title.value, this.refs.price.value) }}>Create New Product</button>
```

and the connect:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onClick: (title, value) => {
      dispatch({                      # This will be a call to addProduct(title, price) later
        type: "ADD_PRODUCT",
        title,
        price
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What ended up working was `<button onClick={ () => {onClick(title.value, price.value) } }>`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally refs are only used when you need to access the DOM for some special reason.  Use props and events.  Something like:

```
<input value={title} onChange={({target:{value}}) => onTitleChanged(value)}/>

// snip

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onTitleChanged: newTitle => dispatch({type: 'SOME_ACTION', value: newTitle})
})
```

Comment: But I need to delay dispatching the ADD_PRODUCT action until both fields are filled in, which is why I have it as an onClick... does it make sense to have an intermediary action like PREPARE_TITLE? How might you represent that in a simple store like `{products:[...]}`?

Comment: I suppose I could modify the store to look like `{products:[...], new_product: { title: 'Cookies', price: null }` on Title Change, then modify the `price` on Price Change, then fold the new_product into the products on Click... is that how redux usually does things?